# Dúvida sobre iteração com múltiplos parâmetros

Tags: c, c++, variáveis, operadores

Este laço realiza o Log_base_2 de um valor inteiro, ao final o resultado fica disponível na variável `i`.

Porque realizar um *shift* da forma `valor >> 1` não surte efeito algum se comparado com `valor = valor >> 1` que por sinal foi a maneira que consegui evitar um *loop* infinito?

```
for(i = 0 ; valor != 1 ; valor >> 1, ++ i); //loop infinito
for(i = 0 ; valor != 1 ; valor = valor >> 1, ++ i); //execução normal
```

Comment: Só um detalhe, parece-me que apenas calcula a parte inteira do log2 do número.

Comment: Sim, isto foi intencional. Usei para manipular os bits de uma word em um simulador de memória cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O primeiro está apenas calculando um número e jogando fora, não guarda em lugar algum, então não tem efeito em lugar algum.

O `++i` tem efeito porque ele é um operador composto. Na verdade ele é a mesma coisa que fazer `i = i + 1`.

Nesse caso específico pode fazer assim `valor >>= 1`, que é o mesmo que `valor = valor >> 1`. Este também é um operador composto, assim como um `i += 1` também.

Comment: A sim, entendi ! Obrigado.